# How this php query generated a selection input field?

Tags: php, wordpress, select

```
<p class="<?php if (get_option('jr_submit_cat_required')!=='yes') : echo 'optional'; endif; ?>"><label for="job_cat"><?php _e('Job Category', 'appthemes'); ?> <?php if (get_option('jr_submit_cat_required')=='yes') : ?><span title="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label> <?php
            $sel = 0;
            if (isset($posted['job_term_cat']) && $posted['job_term_cat']>0) $sel = $posted['job_term_cat']; 
            global $featured_job_cat_id;
            $args = array(
                'orderby'            => 'name', 
                'exclude'            => $featured_job_cat_id,
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'name'               => 'job_term_cat',
                'hierarchical'       => 1, 
                'echo'               => 0,
                'class'              => 'job_cat',
                'selected'           => $sel,
                'taxonomy'           => 'job_cat',
                'hide_empty'         => false
            );
            $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
            $dropdown = str_replace('class=\'job_cat\' >','class=\'job_cat\' ><option value="">'.__('Select a category&hellip;', 'appthemes').'</option>',$dropdown);
            echo $dropdown;
        ?></p>
```

I try to insert  `onchange="changeValue();` into this select field, but I can not find the  field!!
 Yet the code actually generates a select field in the form.

Please help me find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its generating the `<select>` for you, but you could sneak it in near the bottom.

replace this line

```
$dropdown = str_replace('class=\'job_cat\' >','class=\'job_cat\' ><option value="">'.__('Select a category&hellip;', 'appthemes').'</option>',$dropdown);
```

with this

```
$dropdown = str_replace('class=\'job_cat\' >','class=\'job_cat\' onchange="changeValue();"><option value="">'.__('Select a category&hellip;', 'appthemes').'</option>',$dropdown);
```

and it should work as you asked!

Comment: thats great! I am gonna try this out!

Comment: one more question what if I add id? should I just do

Comment: id="myid" *there is space before id and after id"

Comment: Accept the answer if its the solution. Its the 'tick' below the voting up and down buttons :)

Comment: Hi, sry to take off the best answer, but do not know how to get your attention back lol, could you tell me why the onChange is not responding? I heard something I need to make it global because my select n options are generated by php, do you know?

Comment: Thats a completely different problem. Ask another question and provide the javascript for the changeValue();

Comment: Ok, I had posted several, I think this one is related, please check it out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343852/how-do-i-know-i-insert-the-onchange-correctly-into-my-form#comment19940535_14343852