# How do I know I insert the onChange correctly into my form?

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

I inserted a onChange trigger into my selection that generated by php.
But my final result is not responding on the onChange function which runs perfectly in pure html and javascript format.
How can I debug it so that I know the onChange function has been inserted correctly into my select tag?

THank You

**MORE INFO**

This is what actually looks like

```
<p class="<?php if (get_option('jr_submit_cat_required')!=='yes') : echo 'optional'; endif; ?>"><label for="job_cat"><?php _e('Job Category', 'appthemes'); ?> <?php if (get_option('jr_submit_cat_required')=='yes') : ?><span title="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label> <?php
        $sel = 0;
        if (isset($posted['job_term_cat']) && $posted['job_term_cat']>0) $sel = $posted['job_term_cat']; 
        global $featured_job_cat_id;
        $args = array(
            'orderby'            => 'name', 
            'exclude'            => $featured_job_cat_id,
            'order'              => 'ASC',
            'name'               => 'job_term_cat',
            'hierarchical'       => 1, 
            'echo'               => 0,
            'class'              => 'job_cat',
            'selected'           => $sel,
            'taxonomy'           => 'job_cat',
            'hide_empty'         => false
        );
        $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
       $dropdown = str_replace('class=\'job_cat\'id=\'job_term_cat\' >','class=\'job_cat\' onchange="changeValue(this)"><option value="">'.__('Select a category&hellip;', 'appthemes').'</option>',$dropdown);
    ?></p>
echo $dropdown;
```

and here is the tile

```
<p><label for="job_title"><?php _e('Job title', 'appthemes'); ?> <span title="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" class="text"  id="job_title" name="job_title" ></p>
```

and here is the script

```
function changeValue(obj){ document.getElementById('job_title').value= obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}
```

Location of the script in the footer

```
<p class=""><label for="cat">Category <span title="required">*</span></label> <select name="a_cat" id="a_cat" class="cat">
<option class="level-0" value="86" selected="selected">1 a</option>
<option class="level-0" value="93">2 b</option>
<option class="level-0" value="125">3 c</option>
</select>
</p>



<div id="footer">
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeValue(obj){ document.getElementById('title').value= obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}
</script>
</div>
```

Above is the things generated and the footer, do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Can be a case sensitive issue. It is onchange. Can you check if it works.

Comment: @srijan HTML attributes are not case sensitive, which I believe the OP is assigning. Hard to be sure without some code though.

Comment: changed to lowercase onchange, no respond. I just wonder how can I find if my onChange function is even inserted...see my post for updated info

Comment: Your `changeValue` function will need to be in the global scope if you want to do it this way. Make sure you can call `changeValue` from the console. Also I don't see where you're `echo`ing the changed string `$dropdown`.

Comment: Hi, I added echo, I thought it was not so relevant so I did not put it on the code :) Bu how can I make the cangeValue function 'be in the global' scope? I use WordPress doing it.

Comment: Can you show what is the generated HTML for the $dropdown variable, the <p> containing your input job_title and the <script> tag in the footer ?

Comment: I responded by updating the post, plz check it out! thanks!

Comment: @Adam (regarding meta post for question improval) Philippe asked for the generated HTML but anyone reading this question could be interested in it, your final section should explain what it is rather than just saying its a response to philippe. Remember comments are temporary and if you need to read them to understand the question then its not a good question

Comment: @Richard, I do not see the reason to having to konw the footer generated content except that it may because of the script itself inside the footer. which is exactly the same as the previous "and here is the script" simplified version, footer reveal simply the location of the script. thanks

Comment: @Adam I can't really say if its nessissary or not, I'm not a javascript man, but either it is nessissary and you should describe what it is or Philippe was totally wrong (seems unlikely) and it shouldn't be in the question at all

Answer (score 0):

In firefox or chrome you can use `console.log('rock on!')` to see if your `onChange` event is called.

You'll need [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) in firefox or the console explorer in Chrome to see the result

Alternatively, you couls only use `alert('here');` to see if your code runs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, but ...I tpyed console.log('rock on!')....nothing realy happened excpt the rock on! shows.... please see my updated info

Comment: So, you know that your onChange event is called, you can also try a console.log(obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML) to see if this contain any text

Comment: I pasted your code, shows :ReferenceError: obj is not defined....hum, does that mean something wrong with the js itself?

Comment: You need to pus this code in the changeValue function. And this code should execute when the dropdown changes

Comment: like this? <script type="text/javascript">
 function changeValue(obj){ document.getElementById('job_title').value= obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
 console.log(obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}

 </script>

Comment: try commenting the document.getElementById('job_title').value= obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML; line. It's only to make sure obj has a value.

Comment: ok, I did this:function changeValue(obj){ document.getElementById('job_title').value= obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
 //console.log(obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}

Comment: and nothing showup in the console window in the Chrome developer view

Comment: oh wait, sry, my mistake, commented wrong line, now I did below still nothing in console screen, what should I do next?:<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeValue(obj){ //document.getElementById('job_title').value= obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
 console.log(obj[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}
</script>